# Incorrect read string directory when set string from xml

Tags: android

i change default local language, but in android 7 after change configuration to landscape and portrait again and after than open page strings that was set in xml layout read string from default directory!

`java
 android:text="@string/test"`

this string instead of showing --> سلام  ; will be shown --> test ;
but if i set string programmatically in java this will be worked and text is --> سلام  ;

`java
 test.setText(G.context.getResources().getString(R.string.test));`

also i check local language in each change configuration

```java

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    G.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            checkLanguage();
        }
    }, 200);
}

public static void checkLanguage() {

    try {
        String selectedLanguage = G.selectedLanguage;
        if (selectedLanguage == null) return;
        Locale locale = new Locale(selectedLanguage);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        G.context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, G.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        // }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Amazing solution**

in following line of code i used from global context

```
 G.context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, G.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

and after that changed rotation to landscape and again to portrait, **@string/test** that used in xml layout not worked correctly and **'test'** showed, instead of showing persian word **'سلام'** .

**BUT NOW**

i just removed **global context** that filled in **Application** class

```
 getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

***And finally, this problem was solved :)***

Answer (score 0):

when you change configuration to landscape you should have another layout with same name, designed for that and place same text in that.

Comment: i have one xml layout and don't need to use another xml, also this problem is just when i use from android 7